# Excel : how to replace cells that contain a certain value by an empty cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel file with 2 columns of numbers. I would like to plot the second column in fonction of the first one. But I have some 0 in this second column that are errors, and make my curve not so readable.

For instance (my list is my longer and more complex but I don't know how to copy it properly) :

```
0    1
1    3
2    5
3    7
4    0  
5    10
```

The 0 in the fifth line is an error, since the curve is supposed to go up... How can I suppress it and replace it by a blank space ?

```
0    1
1    3
2    5
3    7
4     
5    10
```

**Edit :**  I'll be glad even with VBA codes :)

Comment: Are you comfortable with writing VBA code to achieve this or do you want a "native" solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the column or range you wish to make replacements in.

Press `CTRL` + `H`

In the find box type `0`

Check the box marked 'Match entire cell contents'  *as per comment below ;)*

leave the replace box blank

Press `Replace All`

**Or as a macro:**

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Again using this method you would need to select column or range before using the macro.

Comment: the issue is it finds all the zeros even in the 10 !!!

Comment: I was going to post the exact same answer

Comment: @J.A Ensure you have ['Match entire cell contents'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wHAF.png).

Answer (score 2):

*Do the Following to replace Error with Blank in Selected Range.*

1: Select the Range that you want to work with.

2: Press the `F5`  to open the `Go To dialog box`.

3: Click the `Special button`, and it opens the `Go to Special dialog box`.

4: In the `Go to Special dialog box`, check the `Formula`  and then `Errors` option.

5: Finish with `Ok`.

6: Now, just press `Space Bar` to replace the errors, and finish with  `Ctrl + Enter button`.

*Then you will get all selected error cells are filled with Blanks.*

**As an alternative I would like to suggest VBA Macro to replace Error with Blanks from Selected Range.**

- Add this code to a Command button on your worksheet.
- Select the Range where the Errors may appear and press the Command button.

  ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim R As Range

   For Each R In Selection
   If IsError(R.Value) Then R.Value = Null
   Next
   End Sub
  ```

*It will replace Error with nothing/blanks.*

Answer (score 1):

I would try filtering the data so that it only shows the 0s, then I would use the find and replace function, it should only affect the filtered data, and not the data that also contains 0s e.g 10,20 etc

Regards